# SWF object leaves ghost lines when dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, flash, draggable

Has anyone ever experienced seeing ghost lines when a Flash object is being dragged across HTML canvas? My site has a base element with a nested OpenLayers map on the lowest z-plane followed by one or more draggable jquery ui dialogs containing SWF objects. The dragging appears fine in FF and IE. However, in Chrome, I see ghost lines after I drag... kind of like Chrone not redrawing lower layers.

Before, I didn't use jquery ui dialog (simply used draggable) and didn't see the ghosting. Once I switched to dialog, it began.

I wander whether it is my machine or does anyone else see it? Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFVSr/) on which I also see the lines (similar to my site). However, one the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFVSr/1/), I do not see any ghosting. Attached is a picture of what I'm seeing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a browser bug.

It's a difficult thing to reposition that box being drawn from another application while figuring out who is responsible for redrawing the underlying canvas.

You will probably have to try to come up with a workaround, such as forcing a redraw of the canvas after dragging is done.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem with redrawing bugs in swfobjet and chrome. Solved it removing swfObject alltoghether